# Can't rename item in powershell because it's null

Tags: windows, powershell

qqq.exe exists.

$DB is correct, I use it other times just fine.

```
$DB = Get-Content C:\Users\asd\Desktop\Farm\AccountList.txt
foreach ($x in $DB){
    Rename-Item C:\Users\asd\Desktop\Farm\$x\qqq.exe $x.exe
}
```

Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is null.
At C:\Users\asd\Desktop\Farm\test2.ps1:3 char:57
+ Rename-Item C:\Users\asd\Desktop\Farm\$x\qqq.exe $x.exe
+                                                         ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: `$x.exe` -> `"$x.exe"`

Answer (score 1):

When the powershell parser sees an argument starting with a `$`, it treats it as an expression, meaning that it will try to evaluate it as code.

Since the string `$x` doesn't have a property named `exe`, the expression results in `$null` and `Rename-Item` throws the error you see.

If you use a double-quoted string instead, the parser will stop evaluating `$x` after the dot:

```
Rename-Item C:\Users\asd\Desktop\Farm\$x\qqq.exe "$x.exe"
```

---

*From [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx)*:

> ```
> When processing a command, the Windows PowerShell parser operates
> in expression mode or in argument mode: 
>
>     - In expression mode, character string values must be contained in
>       quotation marks. Numbers not enclosed in quotation marks are treated
>       as numerical values (rather than as a series of characters). 
>
>     - In argument mode, each value is treated as an expandable string 
>       unless it begins with one of the following special characters: dollar
>       sign ($), at sign (@), single quotation mark ('), double quotation
>       mark ("), or an opening parenthesis (().
> ```

Comment: "$($x).exe" will be more proper for future use :-)